# Bundling individual files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a page in my MVC application with only one JavaScript file in it. Should I bundle this file or keep it as is?

My current code

 `@section scripts{
     <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Home/Index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still suggest you put that file through bundling, advantages you get:

1. It will get minified for production
2. Should you add more javascript files later, it will be just a matter of adding those to a bundle, without ever making changes to your HTML template